# how to read input from console if reached the end of file in java?

Tags: java, input

I'm writing a program for reading a input from a text file, and when it reached the end of the file I should get input from console. I wrote the code, but it seems not working correctly. Does anyone have any suggestion?

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    PQHeap newsFeed = new PQHeap();
    if (args.length < 2) {
        System.out.println("Usage: java NewsFeed inputFile commandFile");
    }
    if (args.length == 2) {
        try {
            BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    args[0]));
            String line;

            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] tokens = line.split(",");
                int like = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                int age = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
                newsFeed.insert(tokens[0], like, age);
            }

            BufferedReader command = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                    args[1]));
            BufferedReader commIn = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            boolean done = false;
            String Input = null;
            while (!done) {
                Input = null;
                System.out.println("Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: ");
                if ((Input = command.readLine()) == null) {
                    Input = commIn.readLine();
                }

                if (Input.length() > 0) {
                    char choice = Input.charAt(0); // strip off option
                                                    // character
                    String remainder = ""; // used to hold the remainder of
                                            // input
                    // trim off any leading or trailing spaces
                    remainder = Input.substring(1).trim();

                    switch (choice) {

                    case 'a':
                        newsFeed.insert(remainder, 0, 1);
                        break;

                    case 'i':
                        newsFeed.incrementDay();
                        break;

                    case 'l':
                        String[] tokens = remainder.split(",");
                        int id = Integer.parseInt(tokens[0]);
                        int likes = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
                        newsFeed.increaseLikes(id, likes);
                        break;

                    case 'p':
                        if (remainder.length() == 0) {
                            newsFeed.displayTop(System.out, newsFeed.size());
                        } else {
                            newsFeed.displayTop(System.out,
                                    Integer.parseInt(remainder));
                        }
                        break;

                    case 'q':
                        // exit if user input 'x'
                        done = true;
                        break;

                    default:
                        System.out.println("Unknown Command");
                        break;
                    }

                }
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Cannot find the specified file");
            System.exit(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: an input error has occured");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

But after I reached the end of the file, it does not getting input from console immediately.
Here is the output after reached the end of file

```
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: 
Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q:
```

Comment: done will be changed when input is 'q'. But the code just cannot get input from console when it reached the end of the text file immediately. Every time it will print exactly seven "Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: " when it reached the end of the text file, and after this the program can read input from console.

Answer (score 4):

The `done` boolean, never changes to `true`, causing an infinite loop.

Comment: this is just a part of the code, it does changes to true at the end.

Comment: @user1877939 but not in the loop... If it does, kindly post the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (!done)
```

you are not updating done and it is false it would never go out of while

do something like this

```
        while(!done){

            if((Input = command.readLine()) != null) {
              //not end of file
            }
            else
            {//end of file
                System.out.println("Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: ");
                Input = commIn.readLine();
             }
        }
```

Comment: Your first comment is incorrect. He is reading from two different streams.

Comment: Sorry, I did not post all of my code, but done will be changed when input is 'q'

Answer (score 0):

You are printing `Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q:` outside the loop that checks for end of line from the file. So it will print  that string as number of time as total lines in the file  unnecesarily when the file is being read. Check with code below and I hope it helps.

```
class ReaderTest {
    public static void main(String... args) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader command = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt"));
        BufferedReader commIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        boolean done = false;
        String Input = null;
        while (!done) {
            Input = null;

            if ((Input = command.readLine()) == null) {
                System.out.println("Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: ");
                Input = commIn.readLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But I still need to print "Enter a command - a, i, l, p or q: " if the program takes input from text file

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no problem in the code, but my input file has an error which causing these errors